# Use urllib.urlretrieve and ignore proxy

Tags: python

I'm trying to use [urllib.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) to fetch some files from a server. I need it to ignore any proxy settings on the system however. I have had a look at [urllib.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) but I am not sure how I could use it to download files.

Currently my call looks something like this:

`urllib.urlretrieve(url, import_path + "/%s" % filename)`

Any assistance would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python docs it's said `filehandle = urllib.urlopen(some_url, proxies={})` will cause the system not to us any proxies, even the system's ones.

It's pretty simple to deal with `urlopen()`. `filehandle` supports `read()` method to get data. Open a file then and write that data into it.

Let `filehandle` be full of data after a successful call.

```
fi=open(some_file,mode)
fi.write(filehandle.read())
fi.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd post a complete example.

```
#!/bin/python

import urllib

filehandle = urllib.urlopen("https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html", proxies={})
fi=open("read_this.html", "w")
fi.write(filehandle.read())
fi.close()
```